# Unity3D) Is there a way not to draw line renderer if vertex pos is zero?

Tags: unity, line-renderer

I make a curved line with line renderer.
and a sphere move along it.
i want to draw a line only behind the sphere.

so i do something like this.

``
lr.positionCount = 256;

```
    while (delta < time)
    {    
        lr.SetPosition(i++, curPos);

        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }
```

``

and the problem is, because of i set the size of Positions 256, 
if time is short, there are zero vectors in position. 
so line renderer draw meaningless line.

is there a way to set PositionCount dynamically like List?
or any good way to not draw if positions are zero?

Comment: you can reset positionCount in loop. something like lr.positionCount = i++; 
and it works like List but i don't know how it works inside...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable / Disable LineRenderer Points](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/137277/39518). You could also clip the line in the shader, [similar to this Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136513/39518), setting the cut-off point as a material uniform so it moves as your script dictates.